# PHP - CSS / PHP Includes

Tags: php, include

I am having problems with my php includes and I am wondering if someone can tell what could be wrong with my code.  This is how my file set is broken down.

I have two index files.  one in bank\index.php and one in bank\onlinebanking\index.php.

I have split my header and footer in two different files.  They are listed as
bank\header.inc.php and  bank\footer.inc.php.  I capture my css from my header for the entire website.

header includes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Banking Home Page</title>
</head>

<body class="body">
<link href="../_assets/stylesheets/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<div>

<table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" background="_assets/images/bkrnd_top.png">
  <tr>
    <td width="50%"><img border="0" src="../_assets/images/bkgrnd_tl.png" width="205" height="61"></td>
    <td width="50%">
      <p align="right"><img border="0" src="../_assets/images/logo.png" width="160" height="61"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
<div>

<table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" background="_assets/images/background_headerarea.png">
  <tr>
    <td width="100%"><font face="Arial" size="2"><b>&nbsp;&nbsp; <font color="#FFFFFF">HOME&nbsp;&nbsp; |&nbsp;&nbsp; TBA&nbsp;&nbsp; |&nbsp;&nbsp; TBA&nbsp;&nbsp; |&nbsp;&nbsp; TBA&nbsp;&nbsp; |&nbsp;&nbsp; TBA&nbsp;&nbsp; |&nbsp;&nbsp; TBA</font></b></font></td>

<td>

</tr>


</table>
<?php require_once('login.inc.php'); ?>
```

The problem I am having I cannot get my css or my _assets to render correctly for both of my inex files.

If I change the link to something like src="../_assets/images/bkgrnd_tl.png" it will display correctly in bank\onlinebanking\index.php but it will not display in bank\index.php.  If I change the link to src="_assets/images/bkgrnd_tl.png" it will display in bank\index.php and not in bank\onlinebanking\index.php.

I hope you get the idea what I trying to say.  I would like just one header and footer for all the css to render on all pages.

My includes are as such:

bank\onlinebanking\index.php =

> ```
>         require_once('../websiteconfig.inc.php');
>         require_once('../header.inc.php');    
>     ?>
> ```

bank\index.php

> 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting up some path variables might help you. Then you could provide an absolute path on all your images and css. Something like:

```
define("PATH", "http://www.mysite.com");
```

Then you can do something like:

```
<img border="0" src="<?php echo PATH; ?>/_assets/images/bkgrnd_tl.png" width="205" height="61">
```

You can set up multiple paths that lead to different areas too, like a theme path for example.

Answer (score 1):

The stylesheet link should be included in the header section like this

```
<head>
<link href="../_assets/stylesheets/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is simply that the paths to your various files are different.  For example:

```
home_directory/bank/index.php  
home_directory/bank/onlinebanking/index.php
```

the ".." part of your link path says "go one level higher".

For the first file above that would go to `home_directory/`  However, for the second file it would go to `home_directory/bank`.

You have two potential solutions.  One way is to move all of your code files into the same  directory depth.  For example:

```
home_directory/bank/index.php  
home_directory/onlinebanking/index.php
```

The second, and probably preferable one, is to refer to your additional artifacts through root relative pathing.  In other words instead of using `../whatever` just use `/whatever`

In your case it would be: `href="/_assets/stylesheets/style.css"`

Answer (score 0):

Is/are the CSS file/s being served as text/css? Copy the URL and go directly in it then using Firefox right click and view page info, or use Opera's F4-->Info panel to see the mime/media type. You can also use Fiddler 2.

You can manually set your CSS files to be correctly served in your .htaccess file by using the following...

```
AddType text/css .css
```

If you have more specific needs you can manually set the mime/media type using PHP the following way...

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/css');
?>
```

Comment: I have never used that tag before.  I will check into it thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was create a config file.  From the config file I used an absolute reference.

```
define('ABSOLUTE_PATH', '/home/mjcrawle/bank/');
```

Then i used used the following php include to get it to render correctly.

```
 require_once('../websiteconfig.inc.php');
 include(ABSOLUTE_PATH . 'header.inc.php');
```